@RestControllerAdvice with Custom Serialization
I am refactoring some code and want to change the web service's @RestControllerAdvice error handler to use a different ObjectMapper than the rest of the web service. Currently, the @RestControllerAdvice class circumvents the issue using a serialization library that isn't Jackson.
The web service uses a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to handle serialization globally. It has different serialization options than what the error response needs.
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterForGsError() {
        ...
    }

Then, in the @RestControllerAdvice, you would expect the normal @ExceptionHandlers.
    @ExceptionHandler({ IllegalArgumentException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorModel> handleIllegalArgumentException(final IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
         final ErrorModel error = new ErrorModel();
         ...

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .body(error);
    }

Trying to search for a solution hasn't yielded much, as @RestControllerAdvice becomes @RestController in search results.

It's not a clean way, but have you tried to inject your ObjectMapper in @RestControllerAdvice and serialize response body before returning?
